# Having pipes work with cat and tee

Tags: unix, pipe

I'm implementing pipes for a C++ unix shell, but I'm lost on how to execute the commands.

Let's say I have this command:

```
 cat < inputfile.txt | tee outputfile.txt > outputfile2.txt
```

and I've parsed into an array of c strings terminated with NULL.

How should I approach the execution of this command? Do I go through my array start to end, executing the proper commands whenever I see a '<', '>', or '|' in the order I come by them? Or do I:

1. look for '|' first
2. execute what's on the left (cat < inputfile.txt), redirecting it so it
   writes to a pipe
3. execute what's on the right before the '>' (tee outputfile.txt) and have it read from   the pipe
4. have outputfile2.txt read from outputfile.txt

Comment: Seems like you've got yourself a solution there. What's the question? Edit: running from left to right obviously won't work, because by the time you've `exec`'ed the `cat` binary, it's too late to redirect its input to come from a file.

Comment: I'm not sure if it works

Comment: You will certainly need to split at the pipe (being careful not to spit at the first pipe symbol in `echo "not this | symbol" | cat > output`).  In your example, you create the pipe.  You fork for the left-side child process (LH), and arrange for standard output to go to the pipe. Then you deal with the command and arguments and I/O redirections, noting that `< inputfile.txt cat | ...` works the same as the more orthodox `cat < inputfile.txt | ...`. If there was output redirection, that would override the pipe. Then exec `cat`. The RH child goes through a similar process. _[...continued...]_

Comment: _[...continuation...]_ Meanwhile, the parent process needs to close both ends of the pipe (it is not going to read or write it) and waits for the children (specifically, the RH child, the last process in the pipeline) to finish.  The children end up closing both ends of the pipe after duplicating the relevant end to standard input or output.  (Not closing enough file descriptors is a primary cause of trouble!)  That's not all that different from what you describe, though your step 4 is a little dubious as written, and step 3 needs to deal with the output redirection before `exec*()`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Maybe you should post that as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will certainly need to split at the pipe (being careful not to spit at the first pipe symbol in `echo "not this | symbol" | cat > output`). In your example, you create the pipe. You fork for the left-side child process (LH), and arrange for standard output to go to the pipe. Then you deal with the command and arguments and I/O redirections, noting that `< inputfile.txt cat | ...` works the same as the more orthodox `cat < inputfile.txt | ...`. If there was output redirection, that would override the pipe. Then `exec cat`. The RH child goes through a similar process.

Meanwhile, the parent process needs to close both ends of the pipe (it is not going to read or write it) and waits for the children (specifically, the RH child, the last process in the pipeline) to finish. The children end up closing both ends of the pipe after duplicating the relevant end to standard input or output. (Not closing enough file descriptors is a primary cause of trouble!)

That's not all that different from what you describe, though your step 4 is a little dubious as written, and step 3 needs to deal with the output redirection before `exec*()`.